# Get Actual Rotation and Position Of Child Divs After Rotating Parent Div

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I've a div element which contains three child div's as inline-block display property. I'm applying a rotation transformation with **transform: rotate(15deg)** and the div is rotated. Obiviously all the inner divs are also go along with the parent.

But once the rotation is completed, I want to uncover all the inner elements and they should be at their last position.

How can we get their actual transform origin, rotation and positions.

I tried using `window.getComputedStyle` but not finding any hint in that.

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/mkjangir/pen/paZrjG?editors=1111)

Comment: Do you want animation? There is no animation in codepen.

Comment: I want the actual positions and transform property values of first inner div, so that I can remove the outer div and still apply them explicitly on inner div

Comment: But once the rotation is completed. I didn't get this